# imsi-catcher based on WIFI?

Tags: openwrt, radius

I wanted to get IMSI number on openwrt with freeradius(eap-sim) authenticate but I do not have parameters of kc, rand and SERS.
How to authenticate successfully without these parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Unless the device is using pseudonyms, the IMSI will be provided in the initial EAP-Identity-Response.  You don't need to complete authentication in order to get it.